# Does Java run each conditional operator or does it short-circuit in If statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator

I read somewhere that Java is supposed to 'short-circuit' once the If statement has reached a True boolean. However, I am currently experiencing a null pointer exception in the following code (which I have simplified for the purpose of this question):

```
currentFragment.setTag(HOME);
if( !currentFragment.getTag().equals(PROFILE) | 
        ( currentFragment.getArguments() != null &  
        currentFragment.getArguments().getInt("authorId") != userId) ) { }
```

Android developers will know that setTag() is not a real method, but in my actual code I have made sure that currentFragment.getTag() != PROFILE by error logging. However, when this code runs, it causes a null point exception at

```
currentFragment.getArguments().getInt("authorId") != userId
```

It should short-circuit at the very first condition before the | (OR) operator. Failing that, the next line should make sure the getArguments() != null, so why is it going all the way to the final condition? Can any explain the inner workings of what is going on here. Thanks.

Comment: It will short circuit if you use the short circuit operators.  Otherwise it will not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using `&` instead of `&&`. The former is bitwise AND and will evaluate both sides **always**. The latter stands for logical AND and will do short-circuit conditional evaluation.

More info: [Java Tutorials: Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Solution for your current problem: use logical AND `&&` instead of bitwise AND `&`. Similar for your bitwise OR `|`.

```
if( !currentFragment.getTag().equals(PROFILE) ||
    ( currentFragment.getArguments() != null &&
    currentFragment.getArguments().getInt("authorId") != userId) ) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, an elegant simple explanation. I knew this fairly well, but now it's concrete.

Comment: Thanks! I always wondered why there were two ways of writing that. Is this way also true for PHP? How about when you actually write OR and AND instead of | || or & &&?

Comment: @OmairVaiyani I don't to PHP but a quick search refers to [PHP: Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
& - Bitwise operator for AND
&& - Logical AND (AND gate of Digital logic)
```

The logical AND `&&` performs Short-Circuit

Answer (score 1):

"&" and "|" have two meanings, depending on their operands. Applied to integers, they are bitwise AND and OR respectively. Applied to boolean operands, they are the non-short-circuit versions of logical AND and OR.

People often forget their logical operator meaning, because almost always we use the short-cicuit equivalents, "&&" and "||".